# Trouble with barcode rotation using Lesinowsky plugin

Tags: c#, barcode

Working with this small barcode.dll from Lesinowsky(AKA limilabs barcode plugin). Straight barcode no problem, working as advertised but now I am attempting to rotate barcode image by 90 degrees.
And following error occurs:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Lesnikowski.Barcode.RotationType'
```

Below is exact code which I am using:

```
    string barCode = barCodeTrans + barCodeSeq + barCodeIndex + rotationindex.ToString();
    Lesnikowski.Barcode.Barcode128 bc = new Lesnikowski.Barcode.Barcode128();
    bc.Rotation = 1; -- error goes away once I remove this line but I need to rotate image
    bc.Number = barCode;
    bc.CustomText = "";
    bc.Height = 28;
    bc.NarrowBarWidth = 2;
    Bitmap bcBitMap = bc.GenerateBitmap();
    string fileName = barCode + ".jpg";
    bcBitMap.Save(outputDir + "/" + fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return fileName;
```

Please advise what is wrong and how to fix this unless that DLL no longer supports rotation of the barcode. Then it would be a shame.
Thanks

Comment: you gave the wrong type to bc.Rotation, try `bc.Rotation = Lesnikoski.Barcode.RotationType.{type}`

Comment: Lesnikoski.Barcode.RotationType.{type} produces error before I even compile it.Meaning that VS say that in here .{type} something missing

Comment: even when I put it like that:  bc.Rotation = Lesnikowski.Barcode.RotationType.Degrees90; it returns empty...

Comment: Look at this website, http://www.limilabs.com/barcode/demo

Comment: Thanks for reference I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below working code. Just make sure that when you passing variables to  **string barCode** -- it is not empty or nulls. Single null in that string formation will ruin your day.

```
  string barCode = barCodeTrans + barCodeSeq + barCodeIndex + rotationindex.ToString();
  Lesnikowski.Barcode.Barcode128 bc = new Lesnikowski.Barcode.Barcode128();
  bc.Rotation = Lesnikowski.Barcode.RotationType.Degrees90
  bc.Number = barCode;
  bc.CustomText = "";
  bc.Height = 28;
  bc.NarrowBarWidth = 2;
  Bitmap bcBitMap = bc.GenerateBitmap();
  string fileName = barCode + ".jpg";
  bcBitMap.Save(outputDir + "/" + fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
  return fileName;
```